# Split Expression Into Constant And Non-Constant Summands

Tags: matrix, expression-manipulation, factorization, gathering

I have a partially `t`-dependent matrix which I want to split into its `t`-dependent and its `t`-independent summand. My example for this matrix is

```
m = {{1 + Sin[t], 5}, {7 BesselJ[3, t], a + t + t^2 + t^3}}
```

which I want to split the following way:

> In[1]:= Separate[m,t]
>
> Out[1]:= {{{1, 5}, {0, a}}, {{Sin[t], 0}, {7 BesselJ[3, t], t + t^2 + t^3}}}

such that I get containing one constant and one completely non-constant matrix.

I don't want to use `Integrate[]` for this (so Fourier decomposition is not an option), but `D[]` is fine. I can use manual definitions like `D[a, t]^=0` to tell Mathematica which parameters are constant.

The problem is that my actual functions are much more involved than what I presented here, and all solutions I could come up with are terrible workarounds which I'm afraid might fail occasionally without notice.

Comment: For single valued functions you could try something like  `m /. _[t]->0`

Comment: Thank you, this is an interesting approach. Unfortunately, I also encounter problems when my functions have different levels of nesting of their `t`-dependence (e.g. `Exp[I(1-Sin[w t])]`). However, I will check whether it helps me find a solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I hope this works. It was awkward to construct and I've tested it for a number of cases:

```
getconstants[expr_, var_] := Module[{c0},
  If[expr == 0, Return[0]];
  c0 = CoefficientList[expr, var][[1]]; 
  If[FreeQ[c0, var], c0, 
   Replace[If[Head[c0] === Plus, 
     Select[Replace[c0, Plus -> List, 1], FreeQ[#, var] &], 0], 
    List -> Plus, 1]]]
extractConstantsMtx[mtx_, var_] := 
 Map[getconstants[#, var] &, mtx, {2}]

m = {{Sqrt[a + Sqrt[b]] + Sin[t] Log[a + b], 5}, {7 BesselJ[3, t - a],
     a Sin[x] Cos[x - 1 + Log[2 + b]] + t + t^2 + t^3}};

mc = extractConstantsMtx[m, t];

{m - mc, mc}

(* result: 
  {{{Log[a + b] Sin[t], 0}, {-7 BesselJ[3, a - t], t + t^2 + t^3}},
  {{Sqrt[a + Sqrt[b]], 5}, {0, a Cos[1 - x - Log[2 + b]] Sin[x]}}} *)
```

```
(* test cases *)
extractConstantsMtx[{{0, 0}, {0, 0}}, t]
extractConstantsMtx[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, t]
extractConstantsMtx[{{1 t, 2 t}, {3 t, 4 t}}, t]
extractConstantsMtx[{{1 + t, 2 + t}, {3 + t, 4 + t}}, t]
extractConstantsMtx[{{1 + (1 + t)^2, 2 + (2 + t)^3}, {3 + (3 + t)^4, 4 + (5 + t)^5}}, t]
extractConstantsMtx[{{Sin[t], Cos[t + 1]}, {Tan[t + 2], Log[t - 3]}}, t]
getconstants[Sin[Sin[a + b] + c] + Cos[Sin[d + e] + t], t]
getconstants[BesselJ[y, s + b] + BesselJ[x, t + a], t]
getconstants[Mean[{a, b, Mean[{c, d, e}]}], t]
```

Comment: This breaks if I have a constant like `Sqrt[a + Sqrt[b]]`

Comment: ^ I think I've fixed that by only applying the Plus->List / List->Plus replace at level 1.

Comment: Thank you very much. This really seems far from being an easy solution. For my matrix it still returns some expressions `{}[[1]]`, probably because `0` as a matrix entry is somehow an exception, but apart from this it seems to work entirely correctly. I will do some more tests, too, and I will make sure I understand your code in its entirety.

Comment: @Fred I've fixed cases when expr == 0

Comment: Thank you very much again! Now it really does seem to give me the correct solution, even for my quite complicated matrix. I will spend the following day working with it and later probably mark it as the answer.

Comment: One small (belated) note: When a function contains a time-independent part, it can lead to trouble depending on what the functions are used for. E.g. `Cos[t]^2` equals `1/2(1+Cos[2t])` which has a constant part. The function doesn't take this into account. (It isn't supposed to, but I still wanted to warn people who might use the code blindly for whatever purpose.)